# Show Afform in a popup

Tags: formbuilder

I am trying to embed a link to the case view, which should show an afform in a popup.
Using the hook `civicrm_alterContent` I can embed the link using a simple .tpl file with the following content:

```
{crmScope extensionKey='my-test-extension'}
<a id="myCustomLink" class="crm-hover-button action-item popup" href={crmURL p="civicrm/my-searchKit#?id=`$caseId`"}><i class="fa fa-archive" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;{ts}My custom link{/ts}</a> 
<script type="text/javascript">
  {literal}
  CRM.$(function() {
    let myCustomLink = CRM.$('#myCustomLink').detach();
    CRM.$('div.case-control-panel').children('div').eq(1).children('p').first().append(myCustomLink);
  });
  {/literal}
</script>
{/crmScope}
```

The custom link is properly added and a popup shows up showing the afform, however the rendering of the form does not work properly and url-filter do not work.
The resulting popup looks as following
[image]

An answer in this question does suggest, that this is supposed to work: [Why won't CRM.loadForm render url containing civicrm/a/#?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/27631/why-wont-crm-loadform-render-url-containing-civicrm-a/45425#45425)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure the context exactly, but your code looks functional, although you're using a lot of deprecated javascript syntax (`cj` instead of `CRM.$`, `var` instead of `let`, hardcoded href instead of `{crmUrl}`, to be fair a lot of Civi's code still looks like this and hasn't been updated yet, so I can see where you got your inspiration from ).

Anyway, to your 2-part question:

1. "rendering of the form does not work properly" - Based on your screenshot I think bootstrap.css isn't being loaded. You can fix this by calling `Civi::resources()->addBundle('bootstrap3');`.
2. "url-filter do not work" - Well, in your code example I don't see you passing in any url filter, so I wouldn't expect it to work! Try changing your href to something like `"admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/my-test-afform#?Individual1=123"` or whatever filter you need. It should work.

Comment: You got me with the old javascript. Most of it was copied from an existing extension that did more or less what I wanted to achieve. While I might try to update the javascript I understand your answer such that this should have no functional effect. I edited my question to include a screenshot of the resulting popup.
If the issue would be that the bootstrap theme css is not being loaded, what would be a way to go about it?

Comment: Screenshot does look like missing bootstrap.css. Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the new hints. Adding the bootstrap css to my call of civicrm_alterContent did resolve the rendering issues. However, the url filter do still not work. I edited my code along your suggestion for more modern javascript syntax and added the format of the url parameter I am using. If I open the generated link in a new tab, the SearchKit is displayed with the url parameter working.

Comment: Filters are supposed to work in popups. What version of Civi are you using?

Comment: I am currently on 5.64.4 on a WordPress instanz, which is on version 6.3.2